# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/struts/taglib/TagUtils

Tags: java

I am deploying an application on weblogic 10.3.6. I am using struts 1.3.10, I have my libraries shared on weblogic, and I am referencing it on a weblogix.xml file. The application runs fine when I use the libraries on local, but when I call the shared libraries on weblogic.xml I get the following error:

```
    <Jul 19, 2013 11:24:23 AM VET> <Error> <HTTP> <BEA-101017> <[ServletContext@5597787[app:islr module:islrWeb path:/islrWeb spec-version:null], request: Workmanager: default, Version: 1, Scheduled=true, Started=true, Started time: 2216 ms
[
GET /islrWeb/index.jsp HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Java1.6.0_31
Accept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, */*; q=.2
Connection: Keep-Alive

]] Root cause of ServletException.
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/struts/taglib/TagUtils
    at org.apache.struts.taglib.html.HtmlTag.doStartTag(HtmlTag.java:94)
    at jsp_servlet.__index._jspService(__index.java:110)
    at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspBase.service(JspBase.java:34)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.struts.taglib.TagUtils
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:297)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:270)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:64)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
> 
<Jul 19, 2013 11:24:23 AM VET> <Error> <Kernel> <BEA-000802> <ExecuteRequest failed
 java.lang.NullPointerException.
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.prepareServlet(ServletStubImpl.java:531)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:244)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:184)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.invokeServlet(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:529)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.forward(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:253)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
```

Comment: The only thing that can be said is that the library is not found when you run it.  Make sure all classpaths are correct and all libraries are available

Comment: By the way, is there any reason why you are using struts 1 in 2013 besides college or company constraints?